# My server goes offline when I start my OpenVPN service

Tags: centos, vpn, openvpn

I currently have a VPS with DigitalOcean and setup a OpenVPN following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-6

and this:

http://www.unixmen.com/setup-openvpn-server-client-centos-6-5/

When I type "service openvpn start" in the SSH console, my server immediately goes offline. I can still access my servers SSH through DigitalOcean's online SSH client. From there I checked if openvpn is running properly and everything seems to be ok. I checked my ifconfig and that also seems to be ok. I'm kind of lost at this point. Is this normal?

**EDIT:**

```
   Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: 107.170.42.192:37556 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: 107.170.42.192:37556 [client] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]107.170.42.192:37556
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: client/107.170.42.192:37556 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.6, IPv6=(Not enabled)
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: client/107.170.42.192:37556 MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.6 -> client/107.170.42.192:37556
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: client/107.170.42.192:37556 MULTI: primary virtual IP for client/107.170.42.192:37556: 10.8.0.6
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18175]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18175]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: /sbin/ip route del 10.8.0.0/24
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: Linux ip addr del failed: external program exited with error status: 2
    Jul 24 04:40:53 designfully openvpn[18186]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18222]: OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Sep 12 2013
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18222]: Socket Buffers: R=[124928->131072] S=[124928->131072]
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18223]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18223]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]107.170.42.192:1194
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Sep 12 2013
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: Socket Buffers: R=[124928->131072] S=[124928->131072]
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: ROUTE_GATEWAY 107.170.42.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=04:01:20:b9:d8:01
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully kernel: tun0: Disabled Privacy Extensions
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18226]: /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: GID set to nobody
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: UID set to nobody
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: ifconfig_pool_read(), in='client,10.8.0.4', TODO: IPv6
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: succeeded -> ifconfig_pool_set()
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: IFCONFIG POOL LIST
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: client,10.8.0.4
    Jul 24 04:40:56 designfully openvpn[18234]: Initialization Sequence Completed
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]107.170.42.192:59378, sid=d3e62c34 63ae7ffd
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]107.170.42.192:1194, sid=863e093f df2c985a
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=MI, L=Macomb, O=SimplyJordan, OU=server, CN=SimplyJordan CA, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=jordan@simplyjordan.net
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=MI, L=Macomb, O=SimplyJordan, OU=server, CN=server, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=jordan@simplyjordan.net
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=MI, L=Macomb, O=SimplyJordan, OU=server, CN=SimplyJordan CA, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=jordan@simplyjordan.net
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=MI, L=Macomb, O=SimplyJordan, OU=server, CN=client, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=jordan@simplyjordan.net
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18223]: [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]107.170.42.192:1194
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: 107.170.42.192:59378 [client] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]107.170.42.192:59378
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: client/107.170.42.192:59378 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.6, IPv6=(Not enabled)
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: client/107.170.42.192:59378 MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.6 -> client/107.170.42.192:59378
    Jul 24 04:40:59 designfully openvpn[18234]: client/107.170.42.192:59378 MULTI: primary virtual IP for client/107.170.42.192:59378: 10.8.0.6
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18234]: client/107.170.42.192:59378 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18234]: client/107.170.42.192:59378 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18234]: client/107.170.42.192:59378 SENT CONTROL [client]: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5' (status=1)
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: ROUTE_GATEWAY 107.170.42.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=04:01:20:b9:d8:01
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully kernel: tun1: Disabled Privacy Extensions
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route add 107.170.42.192/32 via 107.170.42.1
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5
    Jul 24 04:41:01 designfully openvpn[18223]: Initialization Sequence Completed
    Jul 24 04:42:57 designfully kernel: atkbd.c: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xe0 on isa0060/serio0).
    Jul 24 04:42:57 designfully kernel: atkbd.c: Use 'setkeycodes e060 <keycode>' to make it known.
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18223]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route del 10.8.0.1/32
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route del 107.170.42.192/32
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route del 0.0.0.0/1
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18234]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18234]: /sbin/ip route del 10.8.0.0/24
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route del 128.0.0.0/1
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18234]: ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18234]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18234]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18223]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18234]: Linux ip addr del failed: external program exited with error status: 2
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18234]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
    Jul 24 04:43:39 designfully openvpn[18223]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
```

EDIT:

```
#################################################
# Sample OpenVPN 2.0 config file for            #
# multi-client server.                          #
#                                               #
# This file is for the server side              #
# of a many-clients <-> one-server              #
# OpenVPN configuration.                        #
#                                               #
# OpenVPN also supports                         #
# single-machine <-> single-machine             #
# configurations (See the Examples page         #
# on the web site for more info).               #
#                                               #
# This config should work on Windows            #
# or Linux/BSD systems.  Remember on            #
# Windows to quote pathnames and use            #
# double backslashes, e.g.:                     #
# "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\foo.key" #
#                                               #
# Comments are preceded with '#' or ';'         #
#################################################

# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh1024.pem 1024
# Substitute 2048 for 1024 if you are using
# 2048 bit keys. 
dh dh2048.pem

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
;cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
user nobody
group nobody

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20
```

Comment: Not really, no!  Could you edit your server's OpenVPN config file into your question, and perhaps the output from `netstat -rn` when the service is up and running?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the line

```
Jul 24 04:40:29 designfully openvpn[18223]: /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Jul 24 04:40:29 designfully openvpn[18115]: /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
```

Each line adds a route for **half** the internet via the OpenVPN tunnel; the upshot is that **all** your network traffic will go down the VPN.

Either your VPN partner is happy to route all your traffic, in which case you should be fine, or they're not, in which case, you shouldn't add that route.

From the fact that you lose connectivity, my **very** strong guess is the latter.  You haven't shown us your config (as asked), so I don't know whether the routes are locally-configured or are being advertised by your OpenVPN partner.  If they're locally-configured, don't do that.  If your OpenVPN partner insists on advertising that route to you, either they need to deal with your traffic, or you need to ignore the route.

Comment: Updated with my config.

Comment: That's odd, it makes no mention of those routes at all.  The logs you posted above, those are from the **server**, not the **client**, yes?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Very strange.  Is there some client who's continually trying to talk to the server, who might be connecting as soon as the service starts up?

Comment: From what I can tell from your logs, I suspect that you've configured both the server and the client parts on the server. That means that the server is trying to connect to itself as soon as the OpenVPN service is started, and then tries to route default through the tunnel to itself. Can you please post a "ps axuw|grep openvpn" to confirm if this is the case?